# Arcpy codeblock returns Syntax Error on arcpy.da.SearchCursor

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I have a file geodatabase in ArcGIS with a list of parking transactions that include start and end time, and a zone.  I want to calculate a field in each row that gives the occupancy in that transaction's zone at the start time, but keep receiving error messages from the expression and code block I use.

This is the expression: `calculate_occupancy(!Zone!, !Parking_Start_date!, !Parking_End_date!)`

Also, I am using the Calculate Field tool in Geoprocessing.

UPDATE:

I've fixed the syntax on the code block and now have this:

```
def calculate_occupancy(zone, start_date, end_date):
    count = 0
    table_name = r"./Default.gdb/Parkmobile"
    field_names = ["Zone", "Parking_Start_date", "Parking_End_date"]
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table_name, field_names) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == zone and row[1] <= start_date and row[2] >= start_date:
                count += 1
    return count
```

The syntax checker confirms it is valid, but now I get the following error:

```
 ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
 Failed to evaluate Arcade expression. [
 Rule name: Zone_Occ,
 Triggering event: Update,
 Class name: Parkmobile,
 GlobalID: ,
 Arcade error: Object not found $featureset,
 Script line: 9]
 Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

This is confusing as $featureset is nowhere in my code.  I have Python selected, but it seems like this is Arcade-related.

Comment: Exclamation marks are not syntactically valid anywhere in Python. What exactly are you trying to do with `!Zone!` etc.?

Comment: These were required to reference the fields I wanted in the expression, but I realize now they don't belong in the code block.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I was able to fix the syntax and have updated the post with a new error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer because you didn't post the part of your code where you use the "calculate_occupancy" function or the line where you used the Calculate Field tool.

From what I understand, the problem is with `CalculateField`, which has an "expression_type" attribute, which could be an ARCADE expression type but you are most likely using a PYTHON3 expression. Try mentioning it by adding `expression_type='PYTHON3'` to the CalculateField method and see if it works.

If not, please post the rest of the code so we can find out the problem and help.